# Facebook graph API returns empty data for a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application that is retrieving data from Facebook.  Users authorize the application to read and write to their pages, and we read their data and post to it from our application.  All interaction occurs via the PHP interface that Facebook supplies.

For the last few months our application has been performing this task flawlessly.  However in recent days we have started noticing an issue with certain pages.

We go out and retrieve data for a specific page, and we no longer get any data.  Instead Facebook returns us an empty result.  This obviously causes problems in our application which needs to read this data.

We can still write data just fine.

I am at a point where I'm not sure what this could be.  Any common scenarios or recent Graph API issues that could cause this?

Comment: Did you look at the raw HTTP responses you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Yes I did, here is a sample var dump of the value returned from FB: 

`["data"]=> array(0) { } `


It's almost like it doesn't like our access tokens and it is blowing up as a result.  That would make sense since you can get graph data just fine in the browser.

These pages could have been accessed with a least three different app ids but I don't think that should matter?  You can have many different graph apps all hitting the same page and they should all still work.

Comment: I found one reason for this. If the page is age limited, or viewable by admins only, then the Graph URL for the page will not work unless the correct access_token is passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds odd. The only thing that comes to mind is that the page owner has put a restriction on the audience for their page, which would then require you to pass in an access token to access data about the page. An example would be a beer company that wants to limit access to their FB page to users that are older than 21. Since there is a restriction on who can access the page content, we enforce that restriction on the FB platform. In this case you would need to pass in the access_token of a user who is 21 or older to access the page details via the graph api.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Jeff's answer, I found that any kind of restriction whatsoever will return a blank data object. I was banging my head on every single setting on my company's page and found that we had it set to only show in certain countries (Manage Settings > Country Restrictions). Removing all of them from the list started to return all the data we needed.